# listing all objects in an S3 bucket using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I have an s3 bucket with a bunch of files that I want to access from my lambda (both lambda and s3 bucket created by the same account):

```
def list_all():
  s3 = boto3.client('s3')
  bucket = 'my-bucket'
  resp = s3.list_objects(Bucket=bucket, MaxKeys=10)
  print("s3.list_objects returns", resp)
```

This gives an error like so:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the 
                   ListObjects operation: Access Denied",
  "errorType": "ClientError",
  "stackTrace": [
  [
    "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
    41,
    "lambda_handler",
    "list_all()"
  ], ...
```

My bucket settings are shown like this on aws:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AddPerm",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

I had two questions:

1) what do I set my Action field to be so that I can list all files in any folder from my lambda using boto3?

2) what should I set my principal to be so that only my aws account (eg when I run my lambda) can access the buckets?

Comment: Using an S3 bucket policy is the wrong way to give your Lambda permissions to your S3 bucket. Instead, create the equivalent IAM role and then configure the Lambda function to use that role.

Comment: I created the iam role and configured the LF to use that role. How do I shut off public access to the bucket?

Comment: Delete the bucket policy.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your lambda is failing is that to use `listObjects`, your **lambda function** need to have the IAM permission `s3:ListBucket` which works against a single bucket (no object wildcard is needed) [(docs)](https://iam.cloudonaut.io/reference/s3/ListBucket.html).

i.e. you should [set your lambda's IAM policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-overview.html) to:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AddPerm",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The OP's policy has a Principal because it's an S3 bucket policy, not an IAM policy. Switching to an IAM policy *and* supplying the policy that you've provided is what's needed.

Comment: Cheers for the spot- didn't notice it was the bucket policy.

Comment: If I dont have a Principal it gives an error, it also gives an error for ListBucket ("policy has invalid action")

Comment: Hi- check my edit, as @jarmod noticed, you need to be editing the _lambda_'s role (on the lambda console press the 'key' icon to view and change the policy).

Answer (score 0):

```py
def list_s3_by_prefix(bucket, key_prefix, filter_func=None):
    next_token = ''
    all_keys = []
    while True:
        if next_token:
            res = s3.list_objects_v2(
                Bucket=bucket,
                ContinuationToken=next_token,
                Prefix=key_prefix)
        else:
            res = s3.list_objects_v2(
                Bucket=bucket,
                Prefix=key_prefix)

        if 'Contents' not in res:
            break

        if res['IsTruncated']:
            next_token = res['NextContinuationToken']
        else:
            next_token = ''

        if filter_func:
            keys = ["s3://{}/{}".format(bucket, item['Key']) for item in res['Contents'] if filter_func(item['Key'])]
        else:
            keys = ["s3://{}/{}".format(bucket, item['Key']) for item in res['Contents']]

        all_keys.extend(keys)

        if not next_token:
            break
    print("find {} files in {}".format(len(all_keys), key_prefix))
```